# Deploy Django 1.6 wsgi

Tags: python, django, deployment, wsgi

Im trying to deploy my Django 1.6 in AWS.

I followed the official tutorial [DEPLOY DJANGO LINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)
And I tried this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        WSGIDaemonProcess typecompilerun.com python-path=/home/ubuntu/my_proj/reborn_auth:/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup typecompilerun.tk
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
```

But gives me this error

```
(my_env)ubuntu@*****:/etc/apache2$ sudo service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
(my_env)ubuntu@****:/etc/apache2$
```

What's the problem? WSGIDaemonProcess at is said in the docs.

Sry if it's basic but I never deployed before

Comment: You first need to load the `mod_wsgi` module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache + WSGI: Address already in use: make\_sock: could not bind to address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915360/apache-wsgi-address-already-in-use-make-sock-could-not-bind-to-address)

Comment: If you haven't installed `mod_wsgi` you can install with this command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi` and this command will enable it `sudo a2enmod wsgi`.